# Built-in ScrollView that scrolls with head motion

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Speaking "ok glass" brings up a command list that automatically scrolls based on the user's head motion.

Is there a built-in UI element in the GDK that implements this? Or will I have to write my own code that uses sensors?

Answer (score 2):

I tried reimplementing parts of this. It's not as shiny as the google one, but those could serve as a starting point:

https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/de/tud/ess/HeadListView.java
https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/de/tud/ess/HeadScrollView.java

Answer (score 1):

I went through the GDK's Developer Guides at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/dev-guides and Reference at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/index and there's definitely no such built-in UI elements in GDK, as of XE 12 released in December 2013.

So the answer for now is yes you have to use sensors to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no native GDK UI element for scrolling a list using sensors (in fact, according to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=484#c6), use of `ListView` at all appears to be discouraged).

However, I was able to get the following to work reasonably well in [my app](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/onebusaway-android/blob/glass/onebusaway-android/src/main/java/com/joulespersecond/oba/glass/ListController.java).  My list is fixed at 4 elements (which helps determine how much scrolling happens), so you can tweak this accordingly (see comments).

```
import com.google.android.glass.media.Sounds;
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.Gesture;
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.GestureDetector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Implements sensor-based scrolling of a ListView
 */
public class SensorListController implements SensorEventListener, GestureDetector.BaseListener {

    static final String TAG = "SensorListController";

    Context mContext;

    ListView mList;

    SensorManager mSensorManager;

    private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mOrientation = new float[9];

    private float[] history = new float[2];

    private float mHeading;

    private float mPitch;

    boolean mActive = true;

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public SensorListController(Context context, ListView list) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mList = list;
        history[0] = 10;
        history[1] = 10;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext);
        mGestureDetector.setBaseListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Receive pass-through of event from View
     */
    public boolean onMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return mGestureDetector.onMotionEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
        switch (gesture) {
            case TWO_LONG_PRESS:
                // Toggle on and off accelerometer control of the list by long press
                playSuccessSound();
                toggleActive();
                return true;
            case TWO_TAP:
                // Go to top of the list
                playSuccessSound();
                scrollToTop();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Should be called from the onResume() of Activity
     */
    public void onResume() {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    /**
     * Should be called from the onPause() of Activity
     */
    public void onPause() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Toggles whether the controller modifies the view
     */
    public void toggleActive() {
        mActive = !mActive;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (mList == null || !mActive) {
            return;
        }

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix, event.values);
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
                SensorManager.AXIS_Z, mRotationMatrix);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mOrientation);

            mHeading = (float) Math.toDegrees(mOrientation[0]);
            mPitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(mOrientation[1]);

            float xDelta = history[0] - mHeading;  // Currently unused
            float yDelta = history[1] - mPitch;

            history[0] = mHeading;
            history[1] = mPitch;

            float Y_DELTA_THRESHOLD = 0.13f;

//            Log.d(TAG, "Y Delta = " + yDelta);

            int scrollHeight = mList.getHeight()
                / 19; // 4 items per page, scroll almost 1/5 an item

//            Log.d(TAG, "ScrollHeight = " + scrollHeight);

            if (yDelta > Y_DELTA_THRESHOLD) {
//                Log.d(TAG, "Detected change in pitch up...");
                mList.smoothScrollBy(-scrollHeight, 0);
            } else if (yDelta < -Y_DELTA_THRESHOLD) {
//                Log.d(TAG, "Detected change in pitch down...");
                mList.smoothScrollBy(scrollHeight, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    private void scrollToTop() {
        mList.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }

    private void playSuccessSound() {
        // Play sound to acknowledge action
        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audio.playSoundEffect(Sounds.SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

I used the above in a `ListActivity`.  I initialize it in `onCreate()`, and here is the method that initializes it:

```
private void initListController() {
    mListView = getListView();
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    mListView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
    mListView.setClickable(true);

    mListController = new SensorListController(this, mListView);
}
```

This also removes the selection indicator from view by making it transparent.

The above controller also uses two finger press to pause/resume scrolling, and a two finger tap to scroll to the top of the list (and acknowledges both these actions with a sound).  Note that for these gestures to work, you will need to override `onGenericMotionEvent()` in your Activity and pass through the event, like:

```
@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // We need to pass events through to the list controller
    if (mListController != null) {
        return mListController.onMotionEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Full source code for this solution can be seen [on Github](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/onebusaway-android/blob/glass/onebusaway-android/src/main/java/com/joulespersecond/oba/glass/ListController.java), and the APK can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/issues/116).