# Similar Google glass menu in my Google Glass app

Tags: menu, google-glass

I would like to implement a menu like Google glass one but inside my application on my Glass.

example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLY21.png

So, after saying "Ok Glass [Name_Of_My_App]", my app will display a menu of items.
Each items are defined by one activity  (or the same activity with a parameter ).

Obviously, I also would like to be able to move down/up my head in order to see the content of my list.

Do you have an idea how I need to do ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23298377/937715.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the voiceMenu module of https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets/tree/master/esslib, it's not perfect, contributions welcome.