# How to scroll a large image using accelerometer

Tags: android

I want to a scoll a large image in both direction horizontally and vertically using accelerometer that shown on this url http://howto.oz-apps.com/2014/02/viewing-image-like-in-facebook-paper-app.html 
if any one have any idea about this then please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457768/moving-an-image-using-accelerometer-of-android

Comment: But id don't want to moving image i want to scrolling image my ImageView is under both Horizontal & vertical Scroll bar and when i set a large image like(1920x1080 pixel or higer) on ImageView it enables both horizontal and vertical scroll bar, by on touching the screen both scroll bar working well but i just want to moving scroll without touching screen i want to move it using accelerometer or any other suitable sensor

Comment: try this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540828/android-listactivity-scrolling-with-accelerometer-issue.. here they are scrolling listview..you try it for imageview.hope so it will help you

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and obviously its helpfull for me